# SSLCipherSuite support in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption, openssl

I have a local Apache2 website and I would like to know if these openssl ciphers have support in Firefox and Chrome or in which ones:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

How can I know that?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't just referenced for the browsers themselves? These look like normal TLS cipher suites to me. Besides that, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: Also see [SSLLabs: User Agent Capabilities](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html),